# Returning Value where no rows returned

Tags: mysql, sql

Table one includes delivery_id
Table two includes the name of store where delivery originated 
Table two includes delivery_id and delivery_events

I'm trying to find specific delivery_id(s) where there is no delivery_event. The issue is that if there is no delivery_event, there is no data stored in table MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT.

What would be the best query to pull deliveries by date where there is no delivery_event - EXTRA would be to have that pull in as a separate column called Event_Status with value failed where there is no corresponding delivery event?

Here's where I am now which is not returning anything:

```
select MO.delivery_id,
DS.name,
MO.created_at

from MAINDB_ORDER MO
join maindb_store DS on DS.id = MO.store_id 

where exists (
select ISNULL (MO.delivery_id
from MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT dwe 
where dwe.id is null)
and MO.created_at between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
limit 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is unclear how the tables are related to each other.

Comment: Hi @etaylor07, your question is described ok but this is not true: "Here's where I am now which is not returning anything:" because this query is not working. Also, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select MO.delivery_id, DS.name, MO.created_at,
       exists (select 1
               from MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT dwe 
               where dwe.delivery_id = mo.delivery_id
              ) as delivery_flag
from MAINDB_ORDER MO join
     maindb_store DS
     on DS.id = MO.store_id 
where MO.created_at between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
limit 1;
```

I am guessing that `delivery_id` is what links the tables.  However, that is speculation because it is not clear from your question what links the tables.

Comment: thanks for your response! Yes, delivery_id is what links the tables. Your query works, however, is not producing any values when I've seen 100+ delivery_id(s) w/o a registered delivery_event in the last month alone. Not sure what else I could add. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might try the LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL pattern.  This will find items in your `MAINDB_ORDER` table that don't have any matches in `MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT` via the `delivery_id` column.

```
SELECT MO.delivery_id
  FROM MAINDB_ORDER MO
  LEFT JOIN MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT MDE ON MO.delivery_id = MDE.delivery_id
 WHERE MDE.delivery_id IS NULL
```

This gets you the delivery_id values present in MO and absent in MDE.  You can add your other WHERE criteria as you wish.

This is equivalent to

```
SELECT MO.delivery_id
  FROM MAINDB_ORDER MO
 WHERE MO.delivery_id NOT IN (
        SELECT delivery_id FROM MAINDB_DELIVERY_EVENT
       )
```

Again, you should add your WHERE clauses as needed.